# Sublime Text 3 - ImportError

Tags: python, sublimetext3, conda

I reinstalled the system lately, and this error never shows up before. When I tried to build a python file today, I got an ImportError which says:

```
ImportError: 
No module named pandas
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
[path: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands]
```

However, the `PATH` environment variable contains the paths:

```
/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
```

I think the problem stems from Sublime Text could not recognize the package paths managed by Conda, but I have no idea why Sublime Text 3 is not recognizing it, since it used to work well automatically with Conda before.

Some more information:

1. Anaconda is installed under `/anaconda3`
2. I installed the package Conda from Sublime Text 3 and launch it from the correct conda environment as well.
3. Packages are installed under `/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

Comment: In your old system, had you manually configured the Python version in Sublime? If so, you need to redo that. IIRC, it does find common Python installs and populate a list for you to choose from, but you still have to choose one somewhere in the Pythons settings.

Comment: Sorry if I did not get you, but doesn’t the error message imply Sublime is not aligned with the user’s ‘PATH’ environment variable?

Comment: I don't think Sublime just grab the first Python executable on the user's PATH. I may be wrong about that (I haven't used Sublime in a long time), but from what I remember, it gathers all the Python executables n the PATH, and also looks in other common location, and uses them all to populate a list of choices somewhere in the settings for the Python addon.